# How to download apps from different OS to USB and then transfer to Ubuntu?

Tags: package-management, usb

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I install software offline?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/974/how-can-i-install-software-offline)

I just installed Ubuntu on my old desktop computer, and I have to say—I freaking love it! Except at the moment I do not have internet connection (i'm using a unsecured connection) and I'm using my Windows 7 Laptop to get a connection to the web.

I would love to install some useful apps on the desktop, but I can't figure out how to do this, is there any way to download Ubuntu/Linux apps on my windows computer and put them into a USB then transfer to the desktop?

Answer (score 4):

[Keryx](http://keryxproject.org/) is what you need.

> Keryx is a free and open source tool for easily managing packages on offline Debian based computers including support for Ubuntu and Linux Mint. It provides an easy graphical interface to help install and upgrade software.

Comment: + 1 This sounds like it should fit the bill, but their description doesn't do a good job of explaining in what situations it would be useful. Alaukik, if you hadn't mentioned this as a solution, I still wouldn't know what keyrx is supposed to be for.